# Откатить уже опубликованный коммит и опубликовать новый, не вызывая мержа у других

Tags: git, git-commit, git-remote

Предположим, я сделал коммит `X` и опубликовал его на удаленный репозиторий (`git push`). Все, у кого есть доступ к репозиторию обновились.

Далее я обычно откатываю коммит через  `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, делаю изменения и пушу через `git push -f origin master`, что полностью удаляет прошлый коммит. Однако, если все снова запулят, то у них будет мерж удаленного коммита с новым.

Как этого избежать?

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил вашу проблему, то не поленитесь отметить ответ "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками" у ответов), чтобы он не висел в списке неотвеченных :)

Answer (score 17):

Если коммит попал в общую/стабильную ветку (т.е. ту, которой пользуется хоть кто-то ещё, обычно это `master`, `develop` и прочие), то его нельзя удалять. Можно только создать «отменяющий» коммит с помощью `git revert` ([подробнее тут, пункт 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxqyU.png)).

Возможно, в вашем коммите оказались какие-то критические данные, например пароли или ключи. В этом случае бесполезно пытаться спасти их с помощью удаления коммита, который их содержит. Данные уже скомпрометированы, все пароли и ключи придётся менять.

```
# отменяем последний коммит, доступный по указателю HEAD
git revert HEAD
# фиксируем отмену в новом коммите
git commit -m'reverted the last commit'
```

Если вы абсолютно уверены, что вы запушили «лишний» коммит в собственную ветку, что её никто не замержил в стабильную ветку и просто так не начал разработку от последнего вашего коммита, можно откатить локальную ветку к предыдущему коммиту, а потом переписать изменения в удалённой ([подробнее тут, пункт 4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxqyU.png))

> Внимание! **Никогда не делайте так с общими ветками (`master`, `develop` и прочие).**
>
> Если это категорически необходимо, обязательно и сразу же предупредите всех, кто работает с этим репозиторием. После переписывания последнего коммита в стабильной ветке им придётся вручную обновлять эту ветку на своей машине. Если у них есть какие-то новые коммиты, предком которых является удаляемый коммит, им придётся делать rebase на  коммит.

```
git reset HEAD^
git push -f
```

Вот вам моя любимая схема, иллюстрирующая разные варианты решения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ух ты, огромное спасибо за схемку, давно хотел что-нибудь такое на работе развесить

Comment: пожалуйста, дайте ссылку на источник блок-схемы чтоб почитать и в нормальном масштабе посмотреть

Comment: @Cerbo а там в верхнем левом углу ссылка мелким шрифтом. Больше ничего нет, я картинку в таком же виде нашёл.

Answer (score 8):

У них скорее всего будет не просто слияние с удалённым коммитом, но будут какие-то проблемы. Ведь у них в репозиториях лежат коммиты с родителем `A`, а в удалённом репозитории лежит *другой* коммит, но тоже с родителем `A`. Я, откровенно говоря, не знаю как поведёт себя git, но единтсвенным правильным решением в данной ситуации является откат всех локальных репозиториев точно так же, как Вы откатитились: `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, только потом `git pull`

Вообще говоря за `git push -f origin master`, в репозиторий, который используется более чем одним человеком, бьют по лицу. Так делать можно только в ЭКСТРЕННЫХ случаях и только если вся команда в курсе происходящего и принимает соответсвующие меры на своих локальных копиях.

Comment: *Я, откровенно говоря, не знаю как поведёт себя git* — единственное встреченное мною поведение для описанной ситуации: программа *git* пытается сделать *merge* локальной и удалённой веток. со всеми вытекающими последствиями при возникновении конфликта.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Git не будет делать push без ключа `--force`. С ним - будет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я писал про поведение при `git pull` из удалённого репозитория, в котором переписана (относительно локального репозитория) верхушка истории.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а, понял. Git скажет, что у вас неактуальная версия и сначала надо делать `pull`, то есть `fetch` + `merge`. И все N-1 разработчиков будут делать каждый свой merge.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, совершенно верно.