# Отмена коммита в гите

Tags: git, git-commit

Подскажите, как убрать изменения коммита "fix server name".
Он уже запушен на сервер. Пробовал удалять через тег - не получается

[image: хистори]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Откатить уже опубликованный коммит и опубликовать новый, не вызывая мержа у других](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429512/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d1%83-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если сервер не допускает изменеие истории (push с параметром --force), то можно воспользоваться командой `git revert`, которая создаст коммит "обратный" к ненужному:

```
git revert COMMIT_HASH
```

Answer (score 7):

Можно откатиться к предыдущему состоянию до последнего изменения. 
Узнайте его индекс через команду:

```
git log

git reset --hard идентификатор коммита
```

Также можете удалить просто последний коммит командой:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

UPD:

Следующая команда отменит последний коммит, но файлы останутся нетронутыми.

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Comment: Добавили бы про `--soft` :)