# Восстановление файлов удаленных через git

Tags: git, github

Создал репозиторий, выгрузил файлы в GitHub. Мне не понравилось название коммита и я его удалил, вместе с ним, как оказалось, удалились все файлы из папки моего проекта на моем пк. Можно ли как-то восстановить файлы?...

---

```
vreiz@kaiser MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/Projects/Frontend/InterfaceDesign/Minimo (main)
$ git reset --hard bd5a68156fd67147c9f2edb8723c9ce376c59f1d
HEAD is now at bd5a681 Добавить .gitattributes, .gitignore и README.md.

vreiz@kaiser MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/Projects/Frontend/InterfaceDesign/Minimo (main)
$ git push --force
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://github.com/Admira1B/admira1b.minimo.io.git

91e7e4d...bd5a681 main -> main (forced update)
```

---

Вот как было выполнено удаление.

---

```
vreiz@kaiser MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/Projects/Frontend/InterfaceDesign/Minimo (main)
$ git reflog
bd5a681 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to bd5a68156fd67147c9f2edb8723c9ce376c59f1d
91e7e4d HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 91e7e4db05eefc55ea44fc76882d5d8989235330
91e7e4d HEAD@{2}: Branch: renamed refs/heads/main to refs/heads/main
91e7e4d HEAD@{4}: commit: Добавьте файлы проекта.
bd5a681 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) HEAD@{5}: commit (initial): Добавить .gitattributes, .gitignore и README.md.
vreiz@kaiser MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/Projects/Frontend/InterfaceDesign/Minimo (main)
```

---

```
$ git fsck --lost-found
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling commit 91e7e4db05eefc55ea44fc76882d5d8989235330
```

---

Выполнил пару команд выше, может помогут в решении вопроса..
Имеется локальный файл коммита в папке lost-found, но я не знаю что делать с ним

Заранее спасибо большое за ответ...

Comment: Спустя 5 мин, после публикации вопроса нашел ответ

```git reset --hard HEAD@{1}```

это команда откатила проект в состояние до выполнения reset и тем самым решила проблему, восстановив все файлы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отмена коммита в гите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870830/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

Решает данную проблему `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`