# Как перенести git с сервера на ветку локального репозитория?

Tags: visual-studio, git

Всем добрый день!

Случайно синхронизировал ветку и теперь не могу перенести с сервера ветки "origin/master" обратно на локальную ветку "unit-testing". Перепробовал и слияние и перемещение,всё безуспешно.

Как откатить изменения с ветки сервера "origin/master" обратно на локальный "unit-testing". Чтобы они были в одной строке где находится "unit-testing" на этом скриншоте?:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у себя локально — никак. изменять ссылку "origin/master" нужно на сервере, который скрывается за псевдонимом "origin".

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  -  Хотите сказать в azuredev это надо делать?  Просто там сервер не найти вовсе и есть только перемещение между локальными ветками: https://imgur.com/wL0RGpl

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429519/178576 , только в вашем случае reset надо не на предыдущий коммит делать (`HEAD^`), как в примере, а на тот, что вам требуется (`unit-testing` или что вам там надо). ну выделенное жёлтым в ответе, конечно обязательно к прочтению и пониманию.